# Packaging out-of-the-box SharePoint 2013 solution

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I'm new to SharePoint development and I was assigned to create an out-of-the-box SharePoint solution.  is there any way to package this solution, including the lists and workflows?  Thanks

Comment: Where else you need package? Elaborate your question..

Comment: right click on your project -> Publish -> To Filesystem and you get your `wsp` File which is your package including all specified in the package.

Comment: by the way i'm doing it on SharePoint Online.

Comment: Please elaborate your question with the environment and other specifications